# php laravel insert query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi i am using laravel version "Laravel Framework version 5.2.27
" and also i have created a migrate table successfully. i want to insert users in "users" table

```
use App\User;
public function insert(){
    $insertRecord = User::insert(array($usersDetails));
}
```

but i am getting that issues

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
500

Details
```

And also i am enable debug="true" in laravel.

But i used "use DB;" class insert records was successfully added. what is my mistake?

In my firebug error in chrome response

```
Failed to load response data
```

My route file is

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

});
// Home
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
]);
Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@getRegister');
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@postRegister');
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'gmail',
                            'name', 'password', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
                             'remember_token'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: try adding this line at top 

use Response;

Comment: getting same error

Comment: is that your controller or model ?

Comment: are you calling that controller function through ajax ?

Comment: No direct post using route file only

Comment: Can you add your routing here ?

Comment: and try this once ..
Clear all the compiled views from storage/framework/views, then hit the route and check if it helps.

Comment: after getting 500 exception,did you check error.log?

Comment: have add columns in fillable can you show User Model code?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some code.

In this piece of code the variable `$usersDetails` is not set. Where does it come from?

```
public function insert(){
    $insertRecord = User::insert(array($usersDetails));
}
```

You have `Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@postRegister');` in your routes, which handles the insert, I think? The method in your controller however is called `insert`, so it seems that method is not even called. You should call the right methods in your routes.